# Detecting collisions in Solar System (openGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, collision-detection, collision

i'm working on a project in wich i need to develop a solar system in openGL, then i need to add a rocket and launch it into another planet detecting the collision.

This is the code where i generate the planet, the rocket and the destination:

```
GLfloat dirCoheteX1 = 0.0f;
GLfloat dirCoheteY1 = 0.0f;
GLfloat dirCoheteZ1 = 0.0f;
GLfloat posx = 80.0f;
GLfloat posy = 0.0f;
GLfloat posz = 0.0f;
//Planet
glPushMatrix();
    //Cambiamos el angulo para que tenga una órbita diferente.
    glRotatef(angulo+160,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    glTranslatef(70.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glRotatef(angulo+15,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    glRotatef(270,1,0,0);
    //Carga de texturas
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texturaTerra);
    GLUquadricObj* q=gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(q, GLU_FILL);
    gluQuadricNormals(q, GLU_SMOOTH);
    gluQuadricOrientation(q, GLU_OUTSIDE);
    gluQuadricTexture(q, GL_TRUE);
    gluSphere(q,10,20,20);
    gluDeleteQuadric(q);
    glRotatef(-270,1,0,0);
//rocket
   glPushMatrix();                 
   glTranslatef(dirCoheteX1+0.0f,dirCoheteY1+0.0f,dirCoheteZ1+0.0f);            
   glRotatef(anguloY,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
  glLineWidth(2.5);
  glBegin(GL_LINES);
  glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glVertex3f(15, 0, 0);
  glEnd();
  glPopMatrix();

//Target
glPushMatrix();
//Cambiamos el angulo para que tenga una órbita diferente.
glRotatef(angulo+240,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
glTranslatef(posx,posy,posz);
glRotatef(angulo+15,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texturaSaturno);
    GLUquadricObj* q5=gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(q5, GLU_FILL);
    gluQuadricNormals(q5, GLU_SMOOTH);
    gluQuadricOrientation(q5, GLU_OUTSIDE);
    gluQuadricTexture(q5, GL_TRUE);
    gluSphere(q5,5,20,20);
    gluDeleteQuadric(q5);
glPushMatrix();
```

The planets are generated on X axis and they rotate around the Sun on Y axis. 
Right now i'm adding the rocket's X position to move it from the planet and rotating it in it's Y axis to head it to the planet, but i don't know how to detect the collision correctly.
I'm using this algorithm:

```
dirCoheteX1+=0.05f; //move the rocket 
 anguloY+=0.05f; //rotate the rocket
 dx = posx- dirCoheteX1;
 dy = posy- dirCoheteY1;
 dz = posz- dirCoheteZ1 ; 
 distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz);
 if (distance < (1.0)) {        
    contact = true;        
 }
```

But the collision is being detected before it actually the rocket reaches the target.

Comment: There appears to be some crucial piece of your code missing. Are you sure `contact = false` *before* you test it? What value is `distance` when the contact is assigned `true`?

Comment: To detect the collision you need xyz coordinates and radii of the planet and of the rocket. Where are they in your code?

Comment: You can get pretty good approximation with Newtonian gravity and simple mechanism (adding acceleration, velocity, position on each world tick), this would give better result than adding 0.05f which result in circle motion. To detect collision you simple find distance between objects as you already did, and see if the distance less than the radii, however depends on how near your camera, you may need to adjust the 1.0 error margin threshold.

Comment: @Jongware i've alreay set contact = false. The value distance was giving me the distance betweeen the planet from where the rocket launches and the orbit of the target planet

Comment: @n.m. i've them in other part of my code

Comment: So could the error be in that other part of your code? Just wondering.